# joomla how to install files

Tags: mysql, joomla, sqlsrv

I have a joomla 1.5 with mysql default database and customizations to execute querys on sql server. I created a component to do this integration. But some file I need to put manually.

file in libraries\joomla\database\database\sqlsrv.php to calls sql server

And I create customized buttons for toolbars to load pages without redirect. (libraries\joomla\html\toolbar\button)

My problem is how to do this automatically on component installation? Or have other way to do this ?

Daniel.

Comment: You've hacked into the core Joomla files? Hmm, good luck. Please read the Joomla Documentation before you do anything.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question, but do you want to run J1.5 on SQL server instead of MySQL? J1.5 is EOL why not use 2.5.x or 3.3.x those support SQL natively and converting data and templates from J1.5 to 2.5 is much easier than converting the core to work with SQL. But if you want to this way take a look at the J2.5 core files.

Comment: I'm just add a new class like ...  "class JDatabaseSQLSrv extends JDatabase" to add sqlsrv functionality.

Comment: I used the 1.5 because they had no other version when I built the site ... :) ... I was thinking of switching to 3.0, this is one reason I seek this solution ... to not make it manually again. How would I do this in 2.5 or 3.x?

Comment: Ok, still it will be hard because based on your SQL version some of the querys in components and plungins will fail because they wasn't made to be compatible with MSSQL or PostrageSQL so probably you will need to edit a lots of these querys.

Comment: There are migration tools for J1.5 to J2.5 and probably for 2.5 to 3.X and as I said since 2.5 Joomla natively supports MSSQl. [here is a description to how to migrate 1.5 to higher](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_I_upgrade_from_Joomla!_1.5_to_3.x%3F)

Comment: Hi, I will try to rewrite the component, but this is not the problem. I would like to know how I put the file sqlsrv.php in a especific folder like libraries\joomla\database\database\ or libraries\joomla\html\toolbar\button in a component instalation or have another method to this(add database-sqlsrv class or button class) to Joomla. Sorry I suck to explain, especially in English ... :)

Comment: with this database class (database\mysql.php modified and saved as sqlsrv.php) I can call SQL Server querys using: 

$options['driver'] = 'sqlsrv';
$db =& JDatabase::getInstance( $options );
...
$db->setQuery( $query );
$db->loadObject();

however I do not lose connection with mysql database.

Comment: the problem with the buttons I founded [here](http://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:Using_the_JToolBar_class_in_the_frontend) for 1.5 and to 3.x [here](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Using_the_JToolBar_class_in_the_frontend)... For the database already have the class on 3.x ... :)